# Error with core-js/es6/regexp

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular

I'm having an issue with core-js particularly the core-js/es6/regexp module. It's giving me an error of

```
required in not defined in
../modules/es6.regexp.to-string
```

I'm using core-js 2.4.1. Is this a bug in the particular version?

Comment: You need to add more context here. What is the code that you are trying to compile? It looks like your dependencies are not set up correctly.

Comment: I have a polyfills.ts file that imports a list of core-js functions. All the others ones like es6/array and es6/date loads without issue except for es6/regexp.